# Looping through Python list and program wont access the next item

Tags: python

Im building a simple landscaper game and cant program wont progress to the next available tool in the list. It progresses to scissors but wont progress to lawnmower. I'll include all code since its pretty short.

Here is my list of tools.

```
tools = [
  {
    'name': 'Rusty scissors',
    'cost': 5,
    'profit': 5
  },
  {
    'name': 'Old Lawn Mower',
    'cost': 25,
    'profit': 50
  },
  {
    'name': 'Battery Powered Mower',
    'cost': 250,
    'profit': 100
  },
  {
    'name': 'Team of Students',
    'cost': 500,
    'profit': 250
  }
]
```

Here is my player/landscaper

```
player = {
  'money': 0,
  'tools': [],
  'current_tool': {
    'name': 'Teeth',
    'cost': 0,
    'profit': 1
  }
}
```

and here are my functions of gameplay

```
def buy_tool():

  for tool in tools:
    if player['current_tool'] != tool and player['money'] >= tool['cost']:
      player['current_tool'] = tool
      player['money'] -= tool['cost']
    cut_grass()

def check_money():
  for tool in tools:
    if player['money'] >= tool['cost']:
      buy_tool()
    else:
      cut_grass()
   



def cut_grass():
  print('You currently have $' + str(player['money']) + ' and are using your ' + player['current_tool']['name'] + '.')
  start_cutting = input('Are you ready to cut grass? (y/n)')
  if start_cutting == 'y':
    player['money'] += player['current_tool']['profit']
    check_money()
    

cut_grass()
```

Comment: In your own words, why does `buy_tool` call `cut_grass`? What problem do you intend do solve this way? Also: in your own words, what exactly do you think happens when a function reaches its end, or a `return` statement is executed? Also: do you know what the word `recursion` means? Do you know what a `while` loop is?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Buy tool calls cut grass because that would be the next step after buying the tool (in my mind) and when a function reaches an end I would say it ends the program or calls whatever function/code the last line calls for. I know of recursion conceptually but not in practice. Your answer does make a lot of sense to me though and definitely helps my understanding.

Comment: Don't think of functions as "steps", and don't think of calling a function as "going to" that part of the process - because it doesn't work that way. Each function is a self-contained process that does a computation; and each time you call it, it starts fresh, does the computation and *reports that result back to where it was called*.

Answer (score 2):

Your code searches for the *first* tool that you can afford.  As soon as it finds one -- which is always scissors -- it stops the search and recurs (**bad** design) to `cut_grass`.

```
  for tool in tools:
    if player['current_tool'] != tool and player['money'] >= tool['cost']:
      player['current_tool'] = tool
      player['money'] -= tool['cost']
      break
  
  cut_grass()
```

You have to change your logic to find the most expensive tool.  The easiest way to do this is to reverse the order of your tools list.

Comment: Because the recursive call is inside the loop and also *not* inside the `if` block, it still won't work. The recursive call occurs *unconditionally* after checking the first tool in the list (whether or not it's purchased), and the other tools don't get checked until the recursive call returns (which it won't, because of the bad design).

Comment: Ah ... good catch ... I'm still making dinner ... fixing this ...